# Drag&drop form host to guest does not work on virtualBox

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, virtualbox, virtual-machine, drag-and-drop

I have a w10-64bits machine and I have also a w8-64bits guest machine on virtual box. Even if I have checked the bidirectional option for drag&drop I cannot move any file from host-to-guest. When I drag a file and I hover the mouse with the file attached to it on the virtual machine GUI a black stop icon occurs. I have installed the lastest guest additions for amd64.
[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDtAD.jpg)

Comment: Did you install Guest Extensions in the Guest machine and restart?

Comment: I have installed the latest guest additions.

Comment: I don’t know why that would not work. I use VMWARE Workstation and copy/paste works fine.  I will keep looking. Make sure your Guest network connection is NOT Host Only.

Comment: I put a picture with my setup. Also, the virtualbox is 6.1.34.

Comment: Another thing to try is a different Guest and use Network defauts.

Comment: 5.x vbox could not run w7 or above, 6.0 has the very same drag&drop issue (I upgraded from 6.0.x to 6.1.x because of this bug) and related to network, I have selected NAT, which is ofc the default.